# VB.Net Captcha wait for user input

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, captcha

I am attempting to have a Captcha image copied and displayed in a picturebox.

I am currently using the following code to find the relevant ID, since it is constantly changing when you refresh the page.:

```
           Dim htmlDocument As HtmlDocument = Me.IEMC.Document
            Dim htmlElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection = htmlDocument.Images
            For Each htmlElement As HtmlElement In htmlElementCollection
                Dim imgUrl As String = htmlElement.GetAttribute("id")
                If imgUrl.Contains("wlspispHIPBimg") Then

                    GRABMYDARNIMG!

                End If
            Next
```

That's working alright. I can get it to find the correct ID. But how will I go about copying the image content of this ID, and pasting it into my picturebox?

I have attempted the following:

```
                IEMC.Document.GetElementById(imgUrl).Focus()
                IEMC.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", False, Nothing)
```

But can't seem to paste it anywhere, or not sure on how to properly copy the element.

I have also attempted something like this:

```
Dim O As Object

Set O = WebBrowser1.Document.body.createControlRange()
Call O.Add(WebBrowser1.Document.All("imgcode"))
Call O.execCommand("Copy")

Set Picture1.Picture = Clipboard.GetData
```

But that isn't working in VB.NET. I'm not sure what to try next.

Pasting the image to the picturebox seems easy enough, assuming its being copied to the clipboard. I just use this line of code:

```
PictureBox1.Image = Clipboard.GetImage
```

If anyone know of a way on how to do this, I would be very grateful.

**Note:** *It is not possible to download the image from the URL. It has to be from the already loaded element in the webbrowser. The image url is deleted as soon as the captcha image is loaded once.*

EDIT: Attempted suggestion below.. But cant get it to save any img whatsoever.

```
Dim doc As mshtml.IHTMLDocument = DirectCast(IEMC.Document.DomDocument, mshtml.IHTMLDocument)
                    Dim imgRange As mshtml.IHTMLControlRange = DirectCast(DirectCast(doc.body, mshtml.HTMLBody).createControlRange(), mshtml.IHTMLControlRange)
                    Dim imagename As String = String.Empty
                    Try
                        For Each img As mshtml.IHTMLImgElement In doc.images
                            imgRange.add(DirectCast(img, mshtml.IHTMLControlElement))
                            imgRange.Select()
                            imgRange.execCommand("Copy", False, Nothing)
                            Using bmp As Bitmap = DirectCast(Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap), Bitmap)
                                bmp.Save("C:\captchaPic.jpg")
                            End Using
                            imagename = img.nameProp

                            Exit For
                        Next
                    Catch aaa As System.Exception
                    End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar of saving CaptchaImage to disk and then sending it to decaptcha api. Here is my code it is in c# but you can easily convert:
So save to disk and use that to put to picture box;

```
     IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
     IHTMLControlRange imgRange = (IHTMLControlRange)((HTMLBody)doc.body).createControlRange();
               string imagename = string.Empty;
                 try
                   {
                    foreach (IHTMLImgElement img in doc.images)
                     {
                       imgRange.add((IHTMLControlElement)img);
                       imgRange.execCommand("Copy", false, null);
                       using (Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap))
                                {
                                    bmp.Save(@"captchaimages\captchaPic.jpg");
                                }
                                imagename = img.nameProp;
                                break;

                            }
                        }
                        catch (System.Exception aaa)
                        { 
                        }
```

Comment: Hmm.. I am not quite sure on how to convert this properly.. I have used a code converter, but i cant seem to get it to work. Particularly the imgRange.add and imgRange.execCommand as well as the doc.body.

Comment: Spoke too soon. Got it running, but it never actually saves anything. Like it doesnt actually find the image.

Comment: Took a bit of work (and i had it on hold for a while too) but got it working with the above. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
For Each capimg As HtmlElement In WebBrowser6.Document.Images
    If capimg.GetAttribute("src").Contains("papi/media?") Then
        Dim CD As mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 = CType(WebBrowser6.Document.DomDocument, Global.mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)
        Dim Images As mshtml.IHTMLControlRange = CType(CType(CD.body, mshtml.HTMLBody).createControlRange, Global.mshtml.IHTMLControlRange)
        For Each imgs As mshtml.IHTMLImgElement In CD.images
            If imgs.GetAttribute("src").ToString.Contains("papi/media?") Then
                Images.add(CType(imgs, Global.mshtml.IHTMLControlElement))
                Images.execCommand("Copy", False, Nothing)
                Dim captchaimage As Image
                captchaimage = CType(Clipboard.GetDataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap), Image)
                PictureBox1.Image = captchaimage

            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```